# disabling horizontal robber banding effect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

i am trying to disable horizontal scroll in an webapp and so far no luck... i have no idea what to do right now...been stuck for awhile now !! anyone has any idea on any possible solutions?!

**I used this to disable the vertical one**

```
$('body').on('touchstart','.menuScrolling',function(e) 
{
    if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) 
    {
        e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
    } 
    else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight === e.currentTarget.scrollTop + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) 
    {
        e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
    }
});
```

**and i thought maybe if i change a few variables it should work for horizontal too but nop..**

```
$('body').on('touchstart','.menuScrolling',function(e) 
{
    if (e.currentTarget.scrolLeft === 0) 
    {
        e.currentTarget.scrolLeft = 1;
    } 
    else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight === e.currentTarget.scrolLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetWidth) 
    {
        e.currentTarget.scrolLeft -= 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your code

Comment: oh yeah !! i solved it!!! but from a totally different direction. I used overflow thing to hide the page once it gets animated to the right :) that way the browser won't think its still there anymore

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `L`

```
e.currentTarget.scrolLeft
```

to

```
e.currentTarget.scrollLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post a fiddle of your code.  I will edit my answer to try and help you further.

One idea that came to mind is this (I assume you are supporting only touch devices for this, correct?):

```
$('body').bind ('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```